# Kafka Consumer does not receive "some" of the messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am running a simple set up for Apache Kafka using the APIs for Producer and Consumer.

In order to simulate heavy load, I am

- running multiple instances of the Producer (say 2),
- all of which are sending the same message (message content is a don't care)
- multiple times (say 1000 for each topic)
- to a large number of topics (say 5)

I am running a single Consumer to read messages from all the topics and keep a count of the number of messages processed.

I would expect at the Consumer end to get (2 x 5 x 1000) = 10000 messages.

But the number of messages received is less than expected.

This behavior does not exist for a smaller set of messages (say 50 messages sent to each topic). So I know that it cannot be something wrong with my setup.

Are there some configurations that I am missing here? Or perhaps, Kafka did not receive some messages from the Producer instances and the API is not notifying me?

FYI: This is being run on a single VM hosted in my personal machine. Both Kafka and Zookeeper are on the same machine. I'm not really interested in the performance of the setup as of now. Performance metrics are not valid if some messages go missing.

Comment: Do you process messages sequentially? Or have you protected your messages counter against parallel execution in your consumer?

Comment: Have you checked whether all messages are actually produced to the topic? You can verify using the `GetOffsetShell` tool: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell.

Comment: Can you verify first with command line consumer which is provided by kafka and see of you still have the same problem ?

Comment: @alirabiee : Messages are processed sequentially. No threads in the consumer side.

Comment: @vahid : I've used this tool and the messages are reaching the server. All topics have the full number of messages sent.

Comment: @Confused : The command line consumer is reading all the messages. Incidentally, not sure if this is relevant or not, but there was a slight miss in my configuration for the topic. Instead of providing the zookeeper server as host:port, I missed the port. After adding that, this behavior has not come up again. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Were you able to fix this @GaidinD ? I am having similar issue I think.

Comment: @Hussain I honestly don't remember how this got fixed. I did have an issue with the zookeeper server provided. But I can't remember what fixed it. Perhaps if you could ask a separate question with your problems, I can take a fresh look into it.

Comment: @GaidinD Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918484/python-kafka-consumer-missing-to-poll-some-messages Thanks.