# Python Kafka consumer missing to poll some messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka

The code for my Kafka consumer looks like this

```
def read_messages_from_kafka():
    topic = 'my-topic'
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers=['my-host1', 'my-host2'],
        client_id='my-client',
        group_id='my-group',
        auto_offset_reset='earliest',
        enable_auto_commit=False,
        api_version=(0, 8, 2)
    )
    consumer.assign([TopicPartition(topic, 0), TopicPartition(topic, 1)])

    messages = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=kafka_config.poll_timeout_ms, max_records=kafka_config.poll_max_records)

    for partition in messages.values():
        for message in partition:
            log.info("read {}".format(message))

    if messages:
        consumer.commit()

    next_offset0, next_offset1 = consumer.position(TopicPartition(topic, 0)), consumer.position(TopicPartition(topic, 1))
    log.info("next offset0={} and offset1={}".format(next_offset0, next_offset1))

while True:
    read_messages_from_kafka()
    sleep(kafka_config.poll_sleep_ms / 1000.0)
```

I have realised that this setup of consumer is not able to read all the messages. And I am not able to reproduce this as it's intermittent issue.

When I compare last 100 messages using `kafka-cat` to this consumer, I found that my consumer intermittently misses few messages randomly. What's wrong with my consumer?

```
kafkacat -C -b my-host1 -X broker.version.fallback=0.8.2.1 -t my-topic -o -100
```

There are just [too many ways to consume messages in python](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/98440/kafka.KafkaConsumer). There should be one and preferably only one obvious way to do it.

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating new connection each time you want to read messages? It is better to move KafkaConsumer creation to be above your while True loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem of missing messages in your Kafka client.
I found solution [here](https://blog.datasyndrome.com/a-tale-of-two-kafka-clients-c613efab49df):

```
while True:
    raw_messages = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=1000, max_records=5000)
    for topic_partition, messages in raw_messages.items():
        application_message = json.loads(message.value.decode())
```

Also there is another Kafka client exists: [confluent_kafka.](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) It has no such problem.